# ExtJs: Ext.grid.Panel: Grid refreshes automatically and becomes blank

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using a Grid to display data on a `modal` window. 
It has two columns, 1. Label 2. TextField

The problem I am facing is whenever I enter anything in the textfield and lose focus from that textfield (by pressing TAB or clicking somewhere else), the grid clears itself completely and I get a blank grid!

I know this has something to do with the autoSync property of the Store associated with the grid. 
So I set it to false `autoSync: false`.
After doing this the data gets retained and works fine.

**BUT** when I close this modal window and re-open it with the same store data, I get a blank screen!

Following is my code:

**Model**

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.window.visualsqlquerybuilder.SQLAttributeValueModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {
        name: 'attribute',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {   name: 'attributeValue',
        type: 'string'
    }
]
});
```

**Store**

```
var attrValueStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
   autoSync: true, //tried setting it to false but got error as mentioned above
   model: 'Ext.ux.window.visualsqlquerybuilder.SQLAttributeValueModel'
});
```

**GRID**

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.window.visualsqlquerybuilder.SQLAttributeValueGrid', {
autoRender: true,
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: ['widget.attributevaluegrid'],
id: 'SQLAttributeValueGrid',
store: attrValueStore,
columnLines: true,
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1
})],
columns: [        
    {                        /*Expression */
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        text: 'Attribute',
        sortable: false,
        menuDisabled: true,
        flex: 0.225,
        dataIndex: 'attribute'
    },
    {                           /*Attribute Values*/
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        editor: 'textfield',
        text: 'Values',
        flex: 0.225,
        dataIndex: 'attributeValue'
    }
],
initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

**MODAL WINDOW**

```
var attributeValueForm = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
  title:'Missing Attribute Values',
  id: 'attributeValueForm',
  height:500,
  width:400,
  modal:true,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  closeAction: 'hide',
  items:[
   {
    xtype: 'attributevaluegrid',
    border: false,
    //height: 80,
    region: 'center',
    split: true
   }
  ],
  buttons: [
  {
    id: 'OKBtn',
    itemId: 'OKBtn',
    text: 'OK',
    handler: function () {
        Ext.getCmp('attributeValueForm').close();
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'Cancel',
    handler: function () {
        Ext.getCmp('attributeValueForm').close();
    }
   }
]
});
```

Please help. This is making me go mad!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide details on how you create the Window itself, as it may be part of the problem.

One cause of this can be that you are hiding the window instead of closing it and then creating a new instance when you re-open. This will cause your  DOM to have two windows instances and may not sync the data correctly in the second instance.

Some more details on how you create the actual window would help shed some light on whether this is the case.

Comment: I have added the code of the modal window as well. And yes i am doing `closeAction: 'hide'` on Close. But I am also calling its show method to open it. Hence I dont think there is a new instance getting created.

Comment: Thanks! So the attributeValueForm variable is only created _once_ and then re-used when you open the window the second time?

Comment: yes. That's correct. I have tried `store.commitChanges()` after adding the models but still no change.

Comment: Then I am unfortunately unable to provide any real pointers to where the problem may come from. Just out of curiosity, what's the autoRender parameter supposed to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably want to jail myself after writing this.

The real issue was that I had created a similar grid for a different modal window and since I had copied the code I missed out on changing the ID of the new grid.

**Both grids had the same IDs.**

Changed it now and it is working fine now.

Thanks for your help!